# Lambda being invoked more than once as per CloudWatch

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codebuild, aws-lambda-layers

I have a CodeBuild project where in the Post Build stage where that lambda goes and update the layers of all other lambdas in my environment.

```
post_build:
    commands:
      - echo "Invoking lambda-function-name Lambda function"
      - aws lambda invoke --function-name lambda-function-name --invocation-type RequestResponse --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out response.json
```

I'm getting in CodeBuild logs:

> COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command:
> aws lambda invoke --function-name lambda-function-name --invocation-type RequestResponse --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out response.json. Reason: exit status 255

and the post build stage fails. The lambda which is being invoked has retry count set to 0 and timeout to 10.
In the CloudWatch logs for the lambda which is invoked I can see it being invoked more than once and in the logs I'm just logging the success and failure of the process of the layers being updated on other lambdas.
I don't want it to be invoked multiple times and have the lambda update the layers to all others and not failing the post build stage. Earlier I didn't had `--invocation-type RequestResponse` and added it later to see if it solves but still getting the same issue.

Comment: Ended up using event rule to check for Post Build phase change to trigger the lambda and removed the cli command.